# Convergence criteria for Jacobi method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-differences, poissons-equation

I found this repository on GitHub (solve Poisson equation with a finite difference scheme): https://github.com/blackcata/Poisson_Equation/blob/master/Jacobi.c.

At the end of the function, to check for convergence of the method, the author simply computes the ratio between the residue and the value of the equation at the point $(i,j)$. Where does this come from?

Comment: "Real world" error estimates are usually a bit ad hoc; it sounds like this one is just "if the relative forward error is below my tolerance then terminate". This does not exactly guarantee that the backward error (the important quantity) is small, but in practice it works OK.

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much. But is there any other (simple) way to check for convergence?

Comment: Anything other than a forward error would not be simple. Taking an absolute forward error would generally be unreliable, because if, say, the boundary conditions are homogeneous Dirichlet and the right hand side $f$ is "small", then the solution is also "small". So a relative forward error is a good compromise. However, ideally you would have some approximate backward error (whether through a proof that the backward error is nicely controlled through the forward error, or a direct estimate of the backward error in the program).

Comment: @Ian Ok thank you I got it.